# Qt treeview resizing

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I have got a table view with custom model.I want to resize the table view according to the size of column contents.It has only 1 column.

I have a line edit.On typing the text in line edit, tree view will show the corresponding result.Therefore, the contents of column keeps changing depending on what text is typed in the line edit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want help with your code, show it to us. [ask]

Comment: you could show an image of what you get and another one that you want to obtain, besides is QTreeView or QTableView?